# Issues with dynamic object while passing to different Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp, rest-client

I am populating a dynamic object and sending that object as parameter to a generic class in different assembly. Both the assembly contains Microsoft.CSharp.dll references.

Then class which is accepting dynamic object as parameter contains logic to convert this dynamic object into json string and send it to an external API.  I am using **Restclient** for sending the request.

For eg: Class A is populating dynamic object and Class B is sending Api request.

```
dynamic body = new ExpandoObject();
```

The Problem is i am getting Bad request as response from external API in class B but when i am sending the request from class A it is working as expected.

**EDIT** : I have copied the code of class B and pasted into Class A where i am making the dynamic object. Strange but this time i got the success response with below code.

Here **requestModel** is the dynamic object and i am passing this body to another class as below :

```
    public class service<Model> where Model : class
        {
          public Response Invoke(Model requestModel, ApiConfiguration configuration)
                {

       var client = new RestClient("http://abc");

                    var restRequest = new RestRequest();

                    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("@12", "M0a981");

                    restRequest.Method = Method.POST;

                    restRequest.AddParameter("Application/Json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel), ParameterType.RequestBody);

                    Logger.Instance.WriteLog("Request body  : " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestModel));

                    var tbaResponse = client.Execute(restRequest);
}
}
```

Is there some issues with passing the dynamic object between different assembly.

Comment: So intercept the JSon and compare that from A with that from B ...

Comment: @bommelding : Both are same.

Comment: Then maybe it's not about the dynamic object.  The JSon is what you send.

Comment: See if you can make a [mcve]

Comment: @bommelding : I have updated the issue.